# Screen blinking (out of sync) on specific resolution (Intel Graphics 620)

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, resolution, intel-graphics

I have a Dell Inspirion 13-5378 laptop (i7-7500U CPU, 32GB RAM, Intel Graphics 620 GPU). This machine has a HDMI 1.4b output, which I'm using with a Samsung U32J59 monitor.

Everything works fine if I set the desktop resolution to 1920x1080 60Hz, or 3840x2160 30Hz.

But I don't like 30Hz... Computer use becomes very laggy and unresponsive at 30Hz.

I am aware that the HDMI 1.4b cannot output 3840x2160 at 60Hz. That's why I'm trying to use the next best resolution that I can find, which is **2560x1440 at 60 Hz**.

The thing is: When I select this particular resolution, the refresh rates that Windows shows are not exactly 60 Hz... Instead, it shows **60.011 Hz** or **59.951 Hz**.

[image: Windows Refresh rates]

This small difference makes my monitor blink sometimes... Once every 2 or 3 minutes, sometimes this frequency changes to once every 15 seconds or so. I know it's a sync problem, because the "OSD Overlay" says "HDMI 1" every time it happens... as if I disconnected the cable and connected again.

Here's what makes this problem even weirder:
If I set the monitor resolution to 2560x1440 @ 60.011Hz, WiFi connection becomes unstable. It drops and reconnects once every 5 minutes or so. WiFi router is 2.4Ghz and is 50cm away from computer. This computer doesn't has Ethernet port, only WiFi.

If I use [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) software to add a "Detailed" resolution of 2560x1440 @ 60Hz, Windows will recognize this and set the monitor to the correct refresh rate, and everything works fine!

But then, another issue happens: When I leave the computer for few minutes, it'll try to shut down the monitor to save energy... And when I return and try to use the computer, it freezes. And the only way to use it is to force a power off by holding the power button for a few seconds.

So, in short:

- Intel drivers don't have the correct refresh rates for 2560x1440 resolution.
- WiFi network somehow don't work well if the Screen resolution is set this way. *(I know, right?)*
- CRU does have the correct refresh rates, but it can't do power saving stuff.

Let me advance the most basic questions and it's answers:

- Yes, I swapped the cable. I tried 5 different cables, the best one is a 2.1 certified for 8K and it has only 1 meter in length. Cable is not the problem.
- Yes, Intel Graphics 620 driver is updated. The last version is from May 10, 2022, which is the one that I'm using right now. I also tried the driver that Dell provides, but I had no luck.
- Yes, I tried the HDMI 2 input of the monitor. Same thing.
- Yes, If I disable the power saving feature, everything works fine with CRU... But I would like to keep it enabled. My laptop uses less than 20 Watts on regular use, and the monitor alone spends twice as much. It would be nice to keep it going off when I'm not using it.

So, the question is: Is this a bug on the Intel driver? There's something else I can try to use this monitor with this laptop on 2560x1440@60Hz?

Can somebody with a 4K monitor and a Intel 620 Graphics card test this particular resolution and see if the refresh rates are like mine or not?

Comment: For the Intel GPU driver, are you using the generic Intel one, or the OEM customized one from Dell? If the former, uninstall it via Device Manager, deleting the installation files at the same time via Device Manager, reboot, and install the OEM customized one from Dell to determine if the issue still occurs _(OEMs customize their GPU drivers and generic ones shouldn't be used when that's the case - Intel's installer is usually good at refusing to install the generic when an OEM  customized one exists)_

Comment: Have you tried another laptop/pc and tried 2560x1440 ? Not all panels can display it, even if they are specified as 4k they have the 4k res not the next res down - My monitor here can display that res but very badly and almost unreadable.

Comment: @JW0914, I tried both Intel and Dell drivers. Both works exact same way as I described on the question.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas my monitor can show 2560x1440 pretty nicely, even it not being the native display resolution (which is 3840x2160). I didn't tried another computer tho... I only have this one.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro When you tried both drivers, before trying the next, did you disconnect from the internet by disabling WiFi/unplugging the ethernet cable, then uninstall via Device Manager, ticking the box to _Delete the driver software for this device_? I'm not sure if this is a driver issue, but the aforementioned steps are the only way to rule it out. The reason why these steps are required is if you don't delete the driver software via Device Manager, Windows will auto install graphics drivers if none are installed, without user interaction, either via the driver `.inf`'s or Windows Update

Comment: Try using a USB-C to HDMI adapter and test with that - definitely worth a go

Comment: My computer doesn't has any USC-C ports, @JohnnyVegas

Comment: ok, get a USB3 to HDMI adapter ... will act as a second video card